# How to run multiple functions in one JQuery statement

Tags: jquery, callback

I am trying to call two separate functions: `alertMe1` and `AlertMe2`  in Jquery. I can't figure out the right syntax. I don't want to define the functions inline as I need to reuse them later in the document. I also need the first function alertMe1 to completely finish before the second function alertMe2 starts. What am I doing wrong?

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    alertMe1, alertMe2
});

function alertMe1() {
    alert("Alert1");
} 

function alertMe2() {
    alert("Alert2");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call the functions as you normally would:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    alertMe1();
    alertMe2();
});
```

Comment: Will the first function fully finish before the second one starts?  Or do I need to implement a callback function?

Comment: What is contained within function runs just like any other function so alertMe1 will fully complete before alertMe2 completes. If you had some sort of async call (like an ajax call) within alertme1, that wouldn't complete before alertme2 completes.

Comment: I guess that's what I am trying to do. My first function will actually run a script that might take a while to finish. How would I assure that the first function completes before the second starts?

Comment: Javascript is not an asynchronous language so only in cases where there is some sort of async operation (like an ajax call), a function call has to complete before the next line of code executes.

Comment: Given the original question, my answer is correct, not sure why the down vote. He is asking that alertme1 completes before alertme2. Given his code, this works.

Comment: The first function will need to do following: `function hideListings() {
      for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        markers[i].setMap(null);
        markers = [];
      }
}` It basically hides the markers on Google Maps API. Then the second one will be .$Ajax that will download JSON data. So I guess in this case I should use callback?

Comment: The original answer worked! I marked the correct answer.

Comment: If the second function has the ajax call, there is no need for a callback because the first one will have completed before the second one.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to note is the Javascript compiler does not care what order you declare your functions so long as you declare them. Then you can simply use a callback function, passed as an argument to your first function.

```
  function alertMe1(callback) {
      alert('hello here i am from alert 1');
       setTimeout(function()
       { 
        callback();
       }, 3000);

    } 

    function alertMe2() {
        alert("and now 1 is done here is 2");
    } 

    $( document ).ready(function() {
      alertMe1(alertMe2);
    });
```

Fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/otzuc2oq/

Comment: What exactly callback() does? Is it a predefined function in JQuery?

Comment: @Luke nop, if you look i'm passing alertMe2 as a paramater to alertMe1, callback() is now the same thing as alertMe2();